# JavaScript: Convert date string mm/dd/yyyy to date mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, sql-server, angularjs, date

I receive a string that comes in from SQLserver with the format:

```
'mm/dd/yyyy' or CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [ActivityDate], 101)
```

I need to convert that string value, to an actual date value, but keeping the same date format:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

- I need to format the date is because it comes from SQL server in format '2015-02-18 00:00:00.000' to a page that uses angularJS sort and fileter taken from this example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular

in my table, I have a date column that uses format mm/dd/yyyy, when I type 12/21/2015 I get nothing from the filter even though there are records with this date. The reason why the filter does not work, is because the date even thouhg it displays as mm/dd/yyyy, still has the fromat from sql. The filter works when I type the date 2015-12-21, but that would be misleading to the user.

Does this makes sense?

Comment: Date values don't have a "format". Internally they're integers.

Comment: Split the string, and put it back together again. That gives you a string, if you want a date object, Dai is correct, it has no format.

Comment: it seems as though you aren't clear on how the date datatype works in JavaScript.  My recommendation, therefore, is to use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) that can perform these kinds of tasks for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you can use  [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor that implicitly calls `Date.parse()`

```
new Date('02/21/1994')
//> Date 1994-02-20T21:00:00.000Z
```

+1 to [Claies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies), i recommend to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) too